# How to create simple calendar on android

Tags: android, calendar

I need simple calendar for my android application, in which I can pick a date from it, and read data from database based on picked date. I'm having trouble finding good and simple example of calendar. Does anybody have a source code of simple calendar? 
Thanks!

Comment: Have you ever tried anything before asking question here?

Comment: [See this one](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/)

Answer (score 12):

Checkout these links with source code example, you'll get an idea about it:

[Android-Calendar-Widget](https://github.com/dharmin007/Android-Calendar-Widget)

[Android-Calendar-GridView-Adapter](https://github.com/jrdnull/Android-Calendar-GridView-Adapter)

[android-calendar-provider-tests](http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-provider-tests/source/checkout)

Comment: The third link - http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-provider-tests/source/checkout just prints out Hello World!

Answer (score 7):

The Calendar API is available as of Android 4.0.

Creating new events is done via Intents and does not require any permission. Setting properties of the event is done via Intent extras. The user will be prompted if the event should be created.

For example the following will prompt the user if an event should be created with certain details.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
 intent.setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI);
 startActivity(intent);
```

You can also add dates and time, if this event is repeated and the like. See the comments in the coding for examples.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
 intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
 intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "Learn Android");
 intent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "Home suit home");
 intent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Download Examples");

 // Setting dates
 GregorianCalendar calDate = new GregorianCalendar(2012, 10, 02);
 intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, calDate.getTimeInMillis());
 intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, calDate.getTimeInMillis());

 // Make it a full day event
 intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, true);

// Make it a recurring Event
intent.putExtra(Events.RRULE, "FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=11;WKST=SU;BYDAY=TU,TH");

// Making it private and shown as busy
intent.putExtra(Events.ACCESS_LEVEL, Events.ACCESS_PRIVATE);
intent.putExtra(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY);
```

More about [this article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCalendar/article.html)

and more calendar api tutorials

- [Mobile tut plus tutorials](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-essentials-adding-events-to-the-user%E2%80%99s-calendar/)
- [Official Calender Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html)
- Here is another good [simple calender example](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/) tutorials.

Answer (score 4):

You should use a DatePicker... Because that's the only simple way through which users can pick a date and read data from a database based on that date... But hey you should also show your effort...

Answer (score 4):

Here is a sample calendar app you can go through.
http://droidwalk.blogspot.in/2012/11/android-calendar-sample.html#more