# Calendar view in android application

Tags: android, mobile, view, calendar

I want to show a calendar view which displays days of the week from Monday- Sunday along with the date. Buttons allow you to skip through weeks back and forth? 
Thanks

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977422/how-to-create-simple-calendar-on-android

Comment: no just doing some research at the mo.

Answer (score 0):

Implement google calender API.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/